# I want to pass variable from code behind to aspx.page using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im my aspx.page I have the lines:

```
<asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-Mail</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox  ID="Email" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="textEntry" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
<%MailValidation(Email.Text)%>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegExpValidator"
    CssClass="failureNotification" 
    SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="Email"
    ErrorMessage="<%= ValReturnTxt %>"
    ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">@</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And in my code behind I have:

```
Public ValReturnTxt As String
    Public Sub MailValidation(mail As String)
    'Dim retVal As String
    Dim s As Internet = New Internet
    Dim boolVal As Boolean = IsValidEmail(mail)
    ValReturnTxt = Internet._error        
End Sub
```

The code behind runs very good and gives the answer I want at any time. 
Internet is a `public class` inside of a namespace `Network`
The line `<%MailValidation(Email.Text)%>` acts as I'm expecting
My problem is that I can't have the txt answer assign it in `ValReturnTxt` as `ErrorMessage="<%= ValReturnTxt %>"` in my `RegularExpressionValidator`

Comment: Where does `ValReturnTxt` come from? Is the goal to supply a *dynamic* validation message?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more appropriate to use a [CustomValidation.ServerValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) which would use MailValidation. (The message can be set from there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the control "RegExpValidator" inside your Sub MailValidation().

```
Public Sub MailValidation(mail As String)
    Dim s As Internet = New Internet
    Dim boolVal As Boolean = IsValidEmail(mail)
    RegExpValidator.ErrorMessage = Internet._error ' I added this line.
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like it could be confusing as the *markup* executes a method with a side-effect. If a RegularExpressionValidator had to be used, I'd might hook into the OnPreRender of the RegularExpressionValidator and changing it from their in the code behind.

Comment: I agree. I was presenting a simple solution instead of addressing underlying issues.

Comment: @user2864740 the RegularExpressionValidator is not validate the e-mal as I do... Thanks.